# Issue on sending mail from siteground which gives error SMTP code : 550

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer;      
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                   
$mail->isSMTP();                                         
$mail->Host = "localhost";    
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                                  
$mail->Username = "xxx@xxxx.com";                     
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxx";                              
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                               
$mail->Port = 25;                                       
$mail->From = "xxx@xxxxx.com"    
$mail->FromName = "xxx";    
$mail->addAddress("example@gmail.com", "example");    
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "<i>Helo</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}

?>
```

Mailer Error:

> SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command
>   failed Detail: Missing internal data in the header. Message discarded.
>   SMTP code: 550

Comment: This line is right: $mail->SMTPAuth = false;? shouldn't be true?

Comment: if $mail ->SMTPAuth = true; also, it is raising the same error.

Comment: You could try setting `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great troubleshooter to PHP mail issues in the answer to a related question, [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail).

Among the details are some specifics on headers, which may help. Here are a couple:

> ## Make sure all mail headers are supplied
>
> Some spam software will reject mail if it is missing common headers
>   such as "From" and "Reply-to":

```
$headers = array("From: from@example.com",
    "Reply-To: replyto@example.com",
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION
);
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

> ## Make sure mail headers have no syntax errors
>
> Invalid headers are just as bad as having no headers. One incorrect
>   character could be all it takes to derail your email. Double-check to
>   make sure your syntax is correct as PHP will not catch these errors
>   for you.

```
$headers = array("From from@example.com", // missing colon
    "Reply To: replyto@example.com",      // missing hyphen
    "X-Mailer: "PHP"/" . PHP_VERSION      // bad quotes
);
```